# Including an SVG file and changing it's height

Tags: php, svg, include

I have an SVG file that I want to include using php `include 'svg/file.svg';` the thing is, I want to be able to set a height for that SVG when I include it.

So I figure I'd make a function:

```
function importSVG($file, $height) {
    $svg = file_get_contents($file);

    // magic to set height?

    return $svg;
}
```

However I cannot figure out how to set a height attribute. I'll be using this function 20-30 times per a page perhaps. So I don't want to be regex'ing the entire SVG code, as some of the svg files are big.

Example SVG file:

```
<svg><path d="M.524 7.42C-.318 8.846.342 10 2 10h7c1.657 0 2.317-1.156 1.476-2.58L6.516.72c-.56-.95-1.473-.947-2.032 0l-3.96 6.7z"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Use an XML parser e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Comment: Wouldn't that be super slow if I have like 30+ SVGs to import on a single page?

Comment: I don't see why. You'd need to try it to prove that either way though.

Comment: You are displaying it on a webpage? If this is the case why not use CSS.

Comment: Simple trick from early PHP coding: Edit the SVG file,  add in unique tags, eg: `height="_hh_"`. Then use `preg_replace()` to replace `_hh_` with `$height`. Also since this tag appears in first few lines (or first line), you can safely ignore the rest of the lines in `preg_replace()`

Comment: @frz3993 The height of a rect is an attribute (not a CSS property) and cannot be set via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid modifying the SVG, plus you only need to include it once in the page, if you use the symbol technique.

Make sure your SVG has a viewBox and convert it to a symbol like so:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">

  <symbol id="my-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <!-- <path>s and whatever other shapes in here -->  
  </symbol>

</svg>
```

Then whenever you need to use it, add the following to your page:

```
<svg class="icon-small">
  <use xlink:href="#my-icon" />
</svg>
```

Where that class is defined as:

```
.icon-small {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

Then if you need a larger version, you can do something like:

```
<svg class="icon-large">
  <use xlink:href="#my-icon" />
</svg>

.icon-large {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

```css
.icon-small {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

    
.icon-large {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
      
    <symbol id="my-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="blueviolet" stroke="orange" stroke-width="6"/>
    </symbol>
      
</svg>


<h1> Example </h1>

<svg class="icon-small">
  <use xlink:href="#my-icon" />
</svg>

<svg class="icon-large">
  <use xlink:href="#my-icon" />
</svg>
```